# formal languages write context-free grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I have been confusing a question for 2 days. I think I solved the question, but I don't know if it's true. Can you help me tell me I did it right or wrong?

The question is ;

Write a context-free grammar for the language $$L = \{ w \mid \text{the first, middle and last symbols of $w$ are the same}\}$$ defined on the alphabet $\{0,1\}$.

I found the answer like this.

$S \to 0A0 \mid 1A1$

$A \to 0S0 \mid 1S1$

Thank you from now...

Comment: Your description of the desired language is difficult to understand. A few examples of strings in $L$ would be helpful.

Comment: Also, the CFG you've given doesn't actually produce any strings (in $\{0,1\}^*)$. You need some "base case" options on the right-hand side that allow productions to terminate.

Comment: Doesn't it have to produce 0 and 1 because it is defined over 0.1?

Comment: w starts with the same symbol, ends with the same symbol, and the middle symbol must be the same as the leading and trailing symbol.

Comment: Can you give an example of a string in $L$ and show how your grammar produces it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, a possible grammar could be

$S \to UTU +U$

$T \to 0T0 + 0T1 + 1T0 + 1T1 + U$

$U \to 0 + 1$

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I have one more question. that question is as follows;
B defined on {a, b} and B = {w | The length of w include even number and 11 substring}
Write proper expression of the B language.

Can you help me?

Comment: This is a totally unrelated question, sorry.